# Email with SendGrid is not working in Azure Apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, sendgrid

I need to send email from my code using the below code snippet. It is working fine in my code, but when I deploy the code in microsoft azure I am getting an error as follows.Kindly help me to rectify the issue.

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
            mail.To.Add(email);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net");
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential(EmailUsername, EmailPassword);
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = myCreds;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Error as Follows

[image]

Comment: Try to add a Sendgrid addons in your Azure app. Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email

Comment: I have added the same.. Now also mail from code is working.. but from azure app is not working

Comment: did you try the keys that you generated in Azure.

Comment: Yes.. I have tied via code using the same key.. email is generating..

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43689984/713789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a Solution, I have written some code for getting OS version and Browser version. That was creating issue.